# command invoking new shell and script is broken

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, ksh

I have two commands:

```
/aka/ball/barry/pet elephant/rhino
```

which invoke new shell and I have command

```
cleartool setview "/view/epp/lpp/tpp.sh" $VIEW
```

which also invoke new shell. Is it possible to run both in a single script one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Probably; although it depends. If these shells are designed to be interactive, you can still probably make them work by sending them commands to end the subshells, such as `exit 0`:

```
$ /aka/ball/barry/pet elephant/rhino <<< 'exit 0'
```

If that successfully exits the shell, you can just do it in serial:

```
#!/bin/bash

##
# Your script?

…stuff

/aka/ball/barry/pet elephant/rhino <<< 'exit 0'
cleartool setview "/view/epp/lpp/tpp.sh" "$VIEW" <<< 'exit 0'

…morestuff
```

Without knowing more about the nature of the shells these programs invoke, it's hard to say for sure.